# Wordpress jquery datepicker only highlight posted dates?

Tags: jquery, database, wordpress, plugins

Wordpress jquery datepicker only highlight those dates which contains posts dates only?

Answer (score 0):

```
 I own found solution for this question.

  $(function() {

  var array = [];
  var res=[];
  $.ajax({
   url: 'get_post_dates.php',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType:"JSON",
   success: function(data) {
     for (var i = 0; i <(data.r.length); i++) {
      array.push(data.r[i])
     }
    },
  });
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      return [ array.indexOf(string) != -1 ]
    },
  }); // end datepicker

 }); 

 --
 get_post_dates.php
 $con = mysqli_connect("hostname","db_user","db_pass","db_name");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 $query= "SELECT posted_date as pDated FROM `blog_posts`";
 $result = $con->query($query);
 $array =array();
 while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
   array_push($array,$row["pDated"]);
 }
 echo json_encode( array("r"=>$array));
```